# TcxGridDBBandedColumn how to move inside band and not move outside of the band

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I want in TcxGridDBBandedColumn not to be moved outside of the band. Is that possible? And if how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcxGrid provides a way to get something similar to the behaviour you're envisaging, but it may not give you close enough control over the column-moving behaviour.

Load the Devex demo project 'ExpressQuantumGridViewBandedFixedDemo' and run it.

Notice that you can drag the `Sunday` column header to drag it to a different position in the `Days` band or even into a different band.

Now, in the Object Inspector, select the `btvUsersSchedule.Bands[0]`, open its `Options` tree and set `HoldOwnColumnsOnly` to `True`.

Do the same for `btvUsersSchedule.Bands[0]`.

Once done, columns from the `Days` band can no longer be dragged into either of those bands.

Now, you can move the `Sunday` column only within the `Days` band.

If the above doesn't fully meet the behaviour you would like, please explain why in terms of that demo, because readers who might be able to help will have access to it.

Finally, in the IDE, select the `btvUsersScheduleSUNDAY` column in the Object Inspector.  Open its `Options` tree and set `Moving` to `False`.

Now you can't move the `Sunday` column at all.